# Where do I find my whenever log files?

Tags: ruby, cron, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever, logfile

I'm using the whenever gem for Rails 5.  I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue, and after my default schedule.rb file was created at config/schedule.rb, I added some logging directives

```
# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever
set :environment, "development"

every 10.minutes do
  rake "events:calc_index", :output => {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}
end
```

I restarted my Rails server (not sure if that matters or not) but I don't see these log files created anywhere.  I have verified my crontab was set up by running "crontab -e" and seeing the job

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/newproj && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake events:calc_index '
```

Where are the log files created?

Answer (score 0):

In your schedule.rb file you can specify the redirection options for your commands at a global or command level by setting the 'output' variable. This example is global level:

```
  # adds ">> /path/to/file.log 2>&1" to all commands
  set :output, '/path/to/file.log'
```

and you should put this global level set :output above your job definition, otherwise it wouldn't work
Example:

```
# This works
set :output, {:error => '~/Desktop/z.error.log', :standard => '~/Desktop/z.standard.log'}

every 1.minute do
  command "python ~/Desktop/whe/config/z.py"
end
```

Taken from: https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs

Comment: Yeah but you're hard-coding "~/Desktop/z.error.log" and that directory structure is not present in all my environments.  So my question remains, I set the output as you see in my quesiton, so where will those files be generated?

Comment: You can just use the rails.env to set the path or any configuration instead

Answer (score 0):

According to whenever documentation
https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs

you can define output like this with Rails :

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
```

So for your exemple you can do :

```
every 10.minutes do
  rake "events:calc_index", output: {error: "#{path}/log/error.log", standard: "#{path}/log/cron.log"}
end
```